# Serverless and NewRelic

Tags: python, flask, aws-lambda, newrelic

I'm using the latest version of the Serverless framework and am trying to integrate NewRelic into my applications. I have both Django as well as Flask applications (-> Python!) which I'd like to monitor with NewRelic. I integrated the framework as documented (by wrapping the WSGI application) and set the NewRelic timeout variables accordingly to make sure data is getting sent. 
In my NewRelic dashboard I'm able to see the project but no data is reported. Has anyone had success getting this running?

Thanks!

Comment: Are your lambdas in a vpc?

Comment: Nope, no VPC, everything super plain setup ...

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth trying the manual instrumentation in your main app file instead of the wsgi file to see if thats working.

`import newrelic.agent
newrelic.agent.initialize('/some/path/newrelic.ini')
... YOUR_OTHER_IMPORTS`

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/python-agent/installation-configuration/python-agent-integration#manual-integration

If that works, work backwards towards the wsgi file :) (be sure to restart your app)